# Array in service not found in method angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, angular2-services

hi i have array in servcie and I have a strange problem in the saveData array function is visible but in removeItems no

my service.ts

```
export class FormService {
  myArray = []
  constructor(){
  }
  saveData(key, value) {
    this.myArray.push({
      key: key,
      value: value
    });
   //HERE IS VISIBLE and i can add may elements
    console.log('myArray')
    console.log(this.myArray)
  }
  removeItems(myIndex) {
    //here is not visible is empty 
    console.log(this.myArray)
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**
my component

```
 export class Step3AdditionalServicesComponent implements OnInit {


      constructor(private formService: FormService) {

      }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.stepsGuard.getAccess(false);
      }
      addToMyArray(key,value) {
        this.formService.saveData(key,value)
      }


removeItemFromArray(event) {
    var myIndex = event.target.id;

    console.log('myIndex ' + myIndex);


    this.formService.removeItems(myIndex);
  }
    }
```

my html

```
<button (click)="addToMyArray('key1','simple1')">Add Simle1</button>
<button (click)="addToMyArray('key2','simple2')">Add Simle2</button>
<button (click)="addToMyArray('key3','simple3')">Add Simle3</button>

<button id="1" (click)="removeItemFromArray($event)">Remove 1</button>
<button id="2" (click)="removeItemFromArray($event)">Remove 2</button>
<button id="3" (click)="removeItemFromArray($event)">Remove 3</button>
```

And when i click removeItemFromArray($event) i see index in console

**----SOLUTION----**

I declare my service in component providers and in app.module
my.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css'],
  providers: [FormService] <---delete this and will be working
})
```

@brijmcq Thanks for help

Comment: show the component also

Comment: The information you provided is not enough, how do you use this service?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka i add component and html

Comment: Well where are you trying to remove anything from the array from component?

Comment: @AJT_82 see update

Comment: I see only adding, nowhere are you calling `removeItems`?

Comment: @AJT_82 add remove to component , when i click this i see in console myIndex, next i call to service to remove from array but there myArray is empty

Comment: Could you create a demo for this, plunker/stackblitz, since the code looks good to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156257/discussion-between-kaker-and-ajt-82).

Comment: Where did you provide the service, in the component or in the module?

Comment: @brijmcq i provide service in component @Component({providers:[FormService]}) and in app.module also

Comment: try to remove the provider in your component. It should only be in app.module and let me know if it works

Comment: @brijmcq thanks alot, its working :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, declare your service in the module level and not in the **component** level unless you know what you are doing. You are probably getting the wrong data because if you declare it in component level, you will always get a new instance of `FormService` and the `myArray = []` will always be empty.

You probably know what happens next if you access an empty array by index :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I remove and add elements in my array:

```
  elementsArray = []; 

  addElementList(event) {
    let element = event.data;
    if (!this.elementsArray.includes(element)) {
      this.elementsArray.push(element);
      console.log("Elements in array = " + this.elementsArray);
    }
  }

  removeElementList(event) {
    let element = event.data;
    let index = this.elementsArray.indexOf(element, 0);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.elementsArray.splice(index, 1);
      console.log("Elements in array = " + this.elementsArray);
    }
  }
```